# What does the Pg annotation mean

Tags: technical-drawing, terminology, drafting, drawings

While I am continuing my practice with the German drawings of the V2 rocket, I have come across the  PG designation a couple of times on different drawings.  I originally thought it was for diameter, but its not lining up with some of the other dimensions in the drawing.

In the following drawing PG 21 appears to be dimensioning the the outside of the threads.  however the hole through the bushing is is dimensioned at 21 as well.  There is no physical way they can both be 21.

[image]

In the example below the PG 21 notation is used for both male and female threads and they do appear to line up.  However there seems to be more than a 1 mm difference between the interior 20 mm hole and the threads.

[image]

**What does the PG notation mean?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my google fu failed me last night.  This mornings searches however were more fruitful.

For future seekers what I found is that PG is an [obsolete standard and you can read more about it here.](https://www.gewinde-normen.de/en/pg-thread.html)

Further searching lead me to a website where I found an update for Inventors Thread.xls spreadsheet where a user has added the information to the built in data base. [Scroll to message 13](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-forum/pg-threads/td-p/565938).

The default Thread.xls file is located here:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\Autodesk\Inventor LT 2021\Design Data\XLS\en-US
```

you will need to change Inventor LT 2021 to the version you are using.  I renamed the original file before adding the new one in case I ever wanted to revert back.

Comment: Really good self answer 